# How to avoid exposing IDs of JPA entities to end users

Tags: spring, security, encryption, spring-security

I have an Spring MVC application, which as it stands, **exposes the IDs of JPA entities to users (in hidden html inputs or browser urls)**.

This could allow **a malicious user to perform operations on entities belonging to another user** using their browser.

Can anyone please suggest a solution to this security problem?

- Is **encrypting/decrypting IDs** a good solution?
- If so, in **which layer** (web, service, repository) is it appropriate to do this?
- Which **encryption solution** is recommended (symetric/asymetric)?
- Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, encrypting IDs is not a good idea, more like hiding the real problem. And it would probably be quite tricky to do cleanly. And a malicious user could still intercept another user's requests and use the encrypted Ids to perform attacks.

The real solution is to implement some kind of access control in your business logic, and refuse attempts to access unauthorized resources, such as en entity belonging to another user.

You could implement this logic yourself if it is simple (no shared entities belonging to several users, no groups, just entities belonging to one user, that should be quite straightforward).

You could implement it as a sort of interceptor (using aspect-oriented, add an aspect to your DAO or service methods for example) in order to do it automatically and avoid too much repetitive boilerplate code.

You could also use Spring Security which has some mechanisms for Access Control.

If the needs are more complex, Spring Security can be used to implement a full ACL (Access Control List) system on your domain objects. This is more complex because ACLs are stored separately, so it needs some exxtra infrastructure in the database, and it seems quite complex to configure right, but it is the more flexible and scalable solution in my opinion. I haven't implemented ACLs myself though, so I can't offer much concrete advice on this.

If you insist on hiding the ids from the users, I suggest you don't really encrypt the IDs but use a per-session correspondance table between the real IDs and some randomly generated temporary ones. This way you avoid frequent crypting/decrypting of IDs and make one visible id totally useless for another user.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your idea to use AOP  in order to check whether an entity indeed belongs to some user is very good and I am going to implement it! Do you think I can do away with the encryption then?

Comment: Thanks. I think the encryption would be much less useful then, but it can't hut to have some more security and implement Paulius' proposition too.

Answer (score 4):

There is a better solution. You can keep your user ID's as primary keys for some purposes, but for this particular purpose I would suggest create a column in all the tables you need, for e.g. called: `IDENTIFIER` and generate some strong random ID for it, I am using this to generate ID's:

```
public static String generateId() {
    return UUID.randomUUID().toString().replaceAll("-", "").toUpperCase();
}
```

Then you can use these identifiers in your views. I also wrote a generic method for `JPA` to find entities which have these kind of columns:

```
public T findByGeneratedId(String generatedId) {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = this.entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery cq = cb.createQuery();
    Root<T> entity = cq.from(entityClass);
    CriteriaQuery query = cq.select(entity).where(
            cb.equal(entity.get("generatedId"), generatedId));
    try {
        return (T) this.entityManager.createQuery(query).getSingleResult();
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Note that my column is called `GENERATED_ID` and all entities has a field:

```
@Column(name = "GENERATED_ID", nullable = false, unique = true)
private String generatedId = generateId();
```

This will guarantee the uniqueness and safeness across your entities and there is no need for some complex `encoding/decoding` stuff.

Comment: Hi Paulius! Your solution seems neat! Just one question: what is the `replaceAll("-", "").toUpperCase();` for?

Comment: Using just `UUID.randomUUID().toString()` will generate the ID something like this: `74ad4db8-9271-4d0c-9809-06871eb43628`. I like all characters to be upper case and ID without dashes. So my thing will generate something like this: `E7405B5669C2451A8FC36EDCBEEBA1F0`. This is more nicer for me :)

Comment: Maybe I missed something, but I fail to see how your solution would prevent a user from accessing another user's entities provided he knows the generated ID of it, which seems the same as knowing the original ID ?

Comment: By using UUIDs a malicious user can't use some sort of loop to generate the IDs (1..9999) and delete all entities in that range that are in DB for example.

Comment: I see, it's true that it becomes very hard to randomly or by brute force finding valid IDs.

Comment: Im curious : any good reason not to use these GUIDs as primary key then ?

Comment: @Pierre Henry. As balteo said, it will stop a malicious user from trying to give an ID which is understandable to humans, like: 1,2,3, etc... Yeah you could use GUIDs for primary key, but this will use more database space in terms of relational mapping if other entities will be joined on a primary key. For this purpose it is better to have standard ID's as primary keys.